# angular-ui-tree doesn't work with more than 9 levels

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-tree

I have a directive that use the [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) component inside an asp.net mvc project, it works really great but a major bug appears every time it renders a tree with more than 9 levels.

For this we have an open [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/pull/841), but is still not merged in master branch, anyway, I need to find a workaround, this is my code:

**Directive:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app.users")
    .directive("columnConfigurationA", [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope: {
                    columnConfig: "=columnConfig"                      
                },
                link: {
                    pre: function (scope) {

                    }
                },
                controller: ["$http", "$scope", "$uibModal", "modalMsgSrv",
                    function ($http, $scope, $uibModal, modalMsgSrv) {
                        $scope.columnConfig = [];
                        $scope.carePlans = [];                           


                            getColumnConfiguration(params, $http).success(function (data) {
                                $scope.columnConfig = setVisibleColumns(-1, data.columns);
                                $scope.carePlans = data.carePlans;
                            });                           

                    }],
                templateUrl: '/sbusA/ColumnConfigurationA'
            };
        }]);
function getColumnConfiguration(params, $http) {
    var url = "/SbusA/GetColumnConfigurationA";
    return $http.get(url, { params: params });
}
})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="plan-edit-cont">
<div class="sorteable">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
        <div class="checkbox c-checkbox mb0 mt-sm inline align-top">
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="edition" ng-model="node.show" ng-click="disableChildrens(node)"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="text-inverse inline" ui-tree-handle>
            {{node.title}}
        </div>
        <a role="button" class="flow-icon-sort ml-lg mr fr drag-icon draggable" ng-hide="edition" dnd-handle><i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a role="button" class="flow-icon-plus ml-lg fr drag-icon" ng-hide="edition" ng-click="editVital(node)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-questions-list" ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.columnChilds">
            <li ng-repeat="node in node.columnChilds" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
            </li>
        </ul>

    </script>
    <div ui-tree>
        <ul style="list-style: none;" ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="columnConfig" id="tree-root" dnd-list="columnConfig" dnd-allowed-types="['node']">
            <li ng-if="node.visibleColumn === true" ng-repeat="node in columnConfig" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'" dnd-draggable="node" dnd-type="'node'" dnd-moved="removeVital(node)"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the error that I get when I have more than 9 tree levels:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

Comment: Have you tried add the directive form the linked pull-request https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/pull/841/commits/50954404342cc9b2ad6d2b898b9b264d166a96ce#diff-9b7d0bbe3589eb159f9e4e3745873b7d? Add use it on your tree: `ng-repeat="node in columnConfig" ui-tree-node ui-tree-nodes-renderer`

Comment: @nemesv I am having another issue, about integrating the component in my app, becaues I have a Bundle.config.js, I copied that file to the project, should I reference it from another way?